# Remix always reloads pages when using winston logger

Tags: winston, remix.run

I have a small Remix app that shows `StudyViewCard` components on the main page. This component has a `Link` to `StudyDetail` to get more info about the study.
It works fine. I mean no full page loads while navigation here and there, Remix only loads the required data in the background as expected.

This my code:

```
import { Link } from "@remix-run/react";
import React from "react";

const StudyViewCard: React.FC<IProps> = ({ study }) => {
  const detailLink = `/study-report/${study.studyId}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {study.longName}
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudyViewCard;
```

I try to use winston logger in my app, but it somehow causes pages are fully reloaded on every navigation.

This is my code using winston logger:

```
import { Link } from "@remix-run/react";
import React from "react";
import logger from "~/common/log/Logger";

const StudyViewCard: React.FC<IProps> = ({ study }) => {
  const detailLink = `/study-report/${study.studyId}`;

  logger.debug("Demo");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {study.longName}
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudyViewCard;
```

And this is how I export logger:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
});

export default logger;
```

If I remove the line `logger.debug("Demo");` from the `StudyViewCard` then the app works fine without full reloads. However, if I put the line back then the app still works, but on every navigation reloads the entire page (the full app).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Winston doesn't work in client side

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the logger with a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  logger.debug("Demo");
}, []);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Besides this, useEffect would be good in this simplified example but not really useful in more complex code with lot of log entries.